# Can't change dropdown attribute to visual swatch on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, swatches, color-swatches

I tried to change a dropdown attribute, for color, to a visual swatch on a test magento2 environment but cannot get it working, does anyone have some advice?

When I changed the color attribute to a visual swatch, it broke the relationship for all configurable products in the store with their child products.

- They were no longer displayed on the product edit page for the parent
  configurable product.
- And on the storefront, the configurable product
  still showed the size dropdown but just an empty field where the
  color options should be.
  [image]

After clearing the cache and re-indexing, the issue still remains.

I tried creating the child variation products again, and this time they displayed correctly on the backend and the storefront, but empty fields also appeared on the storefront.
[image]

Comment: I think its a bug of Magento 2. You can check it here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12695

Comment: hi @holly can you please suggest?